# C memory alignment pointer dereference

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

My recollection is that C code, when dereferencing pointers, must make sure that those pointers are aligned for whatever data type you are trying to dereference. That is why i'm confused why the following test code is just working. Floats are supposed to start on `% 4` addressed, so how is this code successfully able to print the float value at address that is not memory aligned for float access?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float x = 1.0f;
  void *q = malloc(32);
  memset(q, 0, 32);
  char *w = (char *)q + 3;
  memcpy(w, &x, sizeof(float));
  printf("%f\n", *(float *)(w));
  return 0;
}
```

In case this matters, I'm compiling on x86 64 bit using GCC 9.3

Comment: Sorry about the original code - It does compile ... as C++. I have cleaned it up so it's pure C now

Comment: x86 supports unaligned access, with a slight performance penalty. You need to try this on a processor that only supports aligned access.

Comment: Try it on a SPARC or ARM processor and you'll likely get `SIGBUS`.

Comment: Some ARMs can do unaligned access as a toggleable setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My recollection is that C code, when dereferencing pointers, must make sure that those pointers are aligned for whatever data type you are trying to dereference.

The C standard does not even define the behavior of trying to create an unaligned pointer, let alone dereferencing it. C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…

> That is why i'm confused why the following test code is just working.

When the behavior of a piece of code is not defined, why should you be confused or surprised by anything it does? It is not specified that it will “work,” and it is not specified that it will not “work.”

> … how is this code successfully able to print the float value at address that is not memory aligned for float access? … I'm compiling on x86 64 bit using GCC 9.3

What switches are you using?

[With `-O3`](https://godbolt.org/z/fcEcz9Pnf), GCC completely eliminates the `malloc`, the `memset`, and the `memcpy`. It simply figures out the program will pass `1.0f` to `printf`, so it does that directly. Alignment becomes irrelevant.

[With `-O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/48cMaxMr7), GCC does copy the data into the unaligned space (using a `movl` instruction instead of `memcpy`) and then loads it again with a `movss` instruction. That works because the hardware supports it. The compiler may use alignment for `float` because it is faster and more efficient, but that does not mean the hardware does not support unaligned loads and stores.

However, even if the hardware does support it, that does not mean you can rely on it. During optimization, the compiler may make assumptions about alignment that fail when the data is not aligned.

Comment: Isn't that UB already because there is no float object at that address? I know that at least C++ has a hard time reconciling dynamic memory allocation, object lifetime and aliasing. But *overlapping* a new float with an existing float object seems to violate even most lenient rules of object creation.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Ignoring the alignment issue, the question of accessing a `float` falls to the aliasing rules, which say one of the ways you can access an object is by a type compatible with its effective type (C 2018 6.5 7). 6.5 6 says if we copy the bytes of an object (the original `float`) into an object with no declared type (the memory we got with `malloc`), the effective type is then the effective type of the object from which the value is copied. So `memcpy(w, &x, sizeof x);` creates an object at `w` with the type of `x`, and the
 rules allow us to load a `float` as a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing a pointer that is not properly aligned triggers undefined behavior.

On an x86/x64 system it will *probably* work but there’s no guarantee of that.  Other architectures could trigger a fault on the same program.